# Nuxt: Page not found '/'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

So I have a new Nuxt.js 3 project and for some reason its not working? Code:

```
// app.vue
  
<template>
    <NuxtRoot>
      <NuxtPage></NuxtPage>
    </NuxtRoot>
    <base href="/">
</template>
```

```
// pages/Nav.vue

<template>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <NuxtLink to="/">
                    Home
                </NuxtLink>
            </li>
            <li>
                <NuxtLink to="/about">
                    About
                </NuxtLink>
            </li>
            <li>
                <NuxtLink to="/blogs">
                    Blogs
                </NuxtLink>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    setup () {


        return {}
    }
}
</script>
```

```
// pages/About.vue

<template>
    <h1>About</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    setup () {


        return {}
    }
}
</script>
```

```
// pages/Blogs.vue

<template>
    <h1>Blogs</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    setup () {


        return {}
    }
}
</script>
```

I tried to use nuxtroot and the base element in the app.vue and it did not work and also tried just the nuxtpage element and nothing else in the template but it still did not work! HELPPPP!!!

More Info:
Used pnpm
no plugins yet since its new
dependencys: pnpm install --shamefully-hoist did --shamefully-hoist because when made told me to do that
made : pnpx nuxi init name
run : pnpm run dev

Comment: you need a pages/index.vue rtm: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/pages/